# What is the setting on httpd.conf that makes pages "unreachable"?

Tags: apache, wampserver, httpd.conf

I am using wampserver and just created a folder to use as documentroot at `c:/webroot`. I know wampserver provides `c:/wamp/www` and `c:/wamp/vhosts` for serving web pages, I just want to know what settings on httpd.conf prevents apache webserver from serving pages located outside the  wamp folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think the other way around. It's not about preventing, it's about allowing the access by configuring your server.
You can change the path in your DocumentRoot (see httpd.conf).
Or create an alias. In httpd.conf add :

`Alias /webroot "C:/webroot"`

and

`<Directory "C:/webroot">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
Require all granted 
</Directory>`

and then open `http://127.0.0.1/webroot`